# Python did not release memory in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, python3

[image: img]
When I had Linux Mint I used python to plot some picture: open the file, read it and plot picture then program jump to another folder open file in the same name print picture and so and so.
Now when I had Ubuntu 22.04 Python do the same but after few loops, the whole memory is used and program killed.

I tried to used del and gc.collect() but nothing work. What is the problem if in the Mint version the program working without eaten whole memory and on Ubuntu 22.04 ate all  memory after a while?

With every iteration memory usage increase till Ubuntu frozen or program is killed.

Comment: What do you mean by Mint version? Plus this is mostly off topic here. Please go on to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) and this question there

Comment: I meant Linux Mint Distribution

Comment: This seems like an attempt to report a bug, but there is insufficient information currently in the Question to recommend whom the bug report should be directed to.